# Gettin error ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Tags: oracle, sql-update, query-optimization

Hi Gurus I am getting the error ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

when executing the below query

```
UPDATE (SELECT CR.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT,
                  CASE
                  WHEN MRG.AMOUNT_USD=0
                  THEN CR.AMOUNT
                  ELSE MRG.AMOUNT_USD
                  END AS AMOUNT_BILAT,
                  CR.ISUPDATED
                  FROM CRS_TT_BILAT_EXCL_MERGE1 MRG,CRS_T_CURRENT_RATES1 CR
                  WHERE SUBSTR(CR.DNIS_CD,1,3)=MRG.DNIS_CD
                  AND CR.PRODUCT_CUST_ID = MRG.PRODUCT_CUST_ID
                  AND CR.ISUPDATED <> 'Y'
                  AND ROWNUM = 1)
                  SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT_BILAT;
                  CR.ISUPDATED = 'Y';
```

I have simplified the above code from the below query

```
UPDATE CRS_T_CURRENT_RATES1 CR
        SET CR.AMOUNT =
          (SELECT 
                  CASE
                  WHEN MRG.AMOUNT_USD=0
                  THEN CR.AMOUNT
                  ELSE MRG.AMOUNT_USD
                  END
                  FROM CRS_TT_BILAT_EXCL_MERGE1 MRG
                  WHERE SUBSTR(CR.DNIS_CD,1,3)=MRG.DNIS_CD
                  AND CR.PRODUCT_CUST_ID = MRG.PRODUCT_CUST_ID
                  AND ROWNUM = 1),

                  CR.ISUPDATED = 'Y'

           WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM CRS_TT_BILAT_EXCL_MERGE1 MRG WHERE MRG.DNIS_CD = SUBSTR(CR.DNIS_CD, 1,3) AND CR.PRODUCT_CUST_ID = MRG.PRODUCT_CUST_ID )
            AND
            CR.ISUPDATED <> 'Y';
```

I was trying to optimize the 2nd query, since the second query uses two selects i was trying to replace that with a single query. Can any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` statement with selecting 1st row for each (AMOUNT_USD, DNIS_CD, PRODUCT_CUST_ID) - `ROWNUM=1` condition from your query:

```
MERGE INTO CRS_T_CURRENT_RATES1 CR
USING (SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT AMOUNT_USD, 
                 DNIS_CD, 
                 PRODUCT_CUST_ID
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AMOUNT_USD, DNIS_CD, PRODUCT_CUST_ID ORDER BY 1) AS ORD_NO
          FROM CRS_TT_BILAT_EXCL_MERGE1
          ) WHERE ORD_NO = 1
      ) MGR
ON CR.PRODUCT_CUST_ID = MRG.PRODUCT_CUST_ID AND
   SUBSTR(CR.DNIS_CD,1,3)=MRG.DNIS_CD 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET CR.AMOUNT = (CASE
                              WHEN MRG.AMOUNT_USD=0 THEN CR.AMOUNT
                              ELSE MRG.AMOUNT_USD
                          END),
                          ISUPDATED = 'Y'
   WHERE ISUPDATED <> 'Y';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chorel I have a doubt regarding the ROW_NUMBER() function, will the function be applied after the ON conditions are met or will it be applied on the inner query first.

Comment: Condition `ORD_NO=1` will be applied to get dataset which then will be matched to CRS_T_CURRENT_RATES1 using conditions in `ON` section of `MERGE`. See how `MERGE` work - link to doc was provided by jonearles.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you have gone with the `ORD_NO = 1` condition then? To add to this how different would be the query if we remove the `ROW_NUMBER()` and `ORD_NO=1`?

Comment: If set of `(AMOUNT_USD, DNIS_CD, PRODUCT_CUST_ID)` is guaranteed to be unique then you may remove `ORD_NO` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, otherwise `MERGE` will return error. `PARTIRION BY` in analytical functions mean that function will return values for each subset of `PARTITION BY` fields independently, in your example for each `(AMOUNT_USD, DNIS_CD, PRODUCT_CUST_ID)` ORD_NO will start from 1, and if there are other rows with same values they'll get 2,3,etc. Condition `ORD_NO=1` ensures that only unique subsets for above fields will be uset to match target table.

Comment: Thanks a ton Chorel, You really are a guru

Comment: Chorel another doubt cant the same be achieved using a `DISTINCT` of in the select or is the `ROW_NUMBER()` function more efficient than `DISTINCT`

Comment: Should work too, and is easier to read. Sometimes easiest solutions are hardest to find :) . To choose solution best to you check execution plans for both versions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Using `MERGE` and `ROWNUM` won't work.

<s>[`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) can help you avoid repeating SQL:</s>

```
MERGE INTO CRS_T_CURRENT_RATES1 CR
USING
(
    SELECT AMOUNT_USD, DNIS_CD, PRODUCT_CUST_ID
    FROM CRS_TT_BILAT_EXCL_MERGE1
)  MRG
    ON
    (
        SUBSTR(CR.DNIS_CD,1,3) = MRG.DNIS_CD
        AND CR.PRODUCT_CUST_ID = MRG.PRODUCT_CUST_ID
        AND ROWNUM = 1  
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    CR.ISUPDATED = 'Y',
    CR.AMOUNT = CASE WHEN MRG.AMOUNT_USD=0 THEN CR.AMOUNT ELSE MRG.AMOUNT_USD END
```

---

**Update**

`ROWNUM` in the `ON` clause works on the updated table, not the data in the `USING` clause.  The example below starts with two identical rows and only one gets updated:

```
create table test1(a number, b number);
insert into test1 values(1, 1);
insert into test1 values(1, 1);

merge into test1
using
(
    select 1 a from dual
) test2
    on (test1.a = test2.a and rownum = 1)
when matched then update set b = 0;

select * from test1;

A  B
-  -
1  0
1  1
```

Comment: Not sure if it will work correctly with rownum. Probably it'll merge only with first row from `USING` clause.

Comment: @Chorel It appears to work, see my update.  But your idea to use an analytic function is good, it can help make the query more readable.

Comment: Sorry - I was right, that it won't work correctly: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f35f/1/1). Notice that only one row was updated.

Comment: @Chorel You're right.  Thank you for taking the time to correct me.

Comment: you're welcome :) - I just knew it because I had similar problem few weeks ago.